# Student exam probability problem

Tags: probability

I have this math problem:

> There are 30 questions on an exam. John knows answer to 25 of them.
>   When does he have bigger probability of passing the exam:
>
> a) He is asked 3 questions and he must answer at least 2 of them correctly
>   b) He is asked 5 questions and he must answer at least 3 of them correctly

My solution would be:

a) 
$$P =\frac{\binom{25}2 \binom{5}1+\binom{25}3 }{\binom{30}3}$$
b)
$$P =\frac{\binom{25}3 \binom{5}2+\binom{25}4\binom{5}1 + \binom{25}5}{\binom{30}5}$$

Is it correct approach?

Comment: Not sure this is complete.  What happens if he gets a question he doesn't know the answer to?  Does he automatically get that wrong or is there some probability that he guesses the answer correctly?  Also, the denominator for $b$ ought to be $\binom {30}5$, no?

Answer (score 1):

The approach is correct, but the denominator of the second answer should be  ${30 \choose 5}$. I guess you know why.

Comment: Oh yes, I copied it from the first fraction and didn´t change it. I already edited the post.